# Issue with references upgrading to TypeScript 0.9.0.alpha

Tags: typescript

We have about a hundred `.ts` files in our project and a dozen `.d.ts` files. On TypeScript 0.8.3 to handle the references we had a single file called `_references.d.ts` that listed all of the definition files in the order of dependency and made sure that it appeared before any other typescript items in the project's `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\_references.d.ts" />
  ...
```

This way all references were resolved correctly without us having to add any references in any of the typescript source files. However, this doesn't seem to work anymore after upgrading to TypeScript 0.9.0.alpha. Right now it does not work even if we make a reference to `_references.d.ts` in every source file and have to go through all of them and include direct references to each definition file. This is going to be a pain, also I don't like this approach because we won't be able to know unused references in each `.ts` file and there's no easy way to clean them up. So my question is, is this pain by design, or is there any other way we can make the compiler happy about references?

Thanks!

Comment: Not only does 0.9 introduce breaking changes to 0.8. You're using an alpha release in a production project. I'd consider at least waiting until it's out of alpha.

Comment: It is on a separate branch. So we want to be compatible with the latest as much as possible and report issues that can affect our code.

Comment: I prefer to use the latest version in production environment. It's only generating javascript and that is human observable. If it was generating binary I would have steered clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found what was the problem. In our `_references.d.ts` file, there was an Interface that was declared at the top of the file before any references. The compiler did not give any informative errors and just ignored those references.

So all `/// <reference path="..." />`'s need to come first in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to have a clear pipeline for TypeScript compilation from the command line, and I suppose that is what has happened.

I like to have a reference.ts in my project. That in turn references all the files in my project. And then each file in my project references this main file as :

```
/// <reference path="references.ts" />
```

Notice **.ts** instead of **.d.ts**

Typescript will work out circular dependencies (between file references ... not types) and you do not need to worry about this.

Compile your project as :

```
tsc --out output.js --declaration
```

and you get a single js + output.d.ts file for reuse in other projects.

Comment: I tried **.ts** instead of **.d.ts** but I see no difference. I don't see anything in the [specs](https://typescript.codeplex.com/downloads/get/672560) (See section 11.1.1) either that say dependencies are handled differently for source files and definition files. The only difference I see is that for **.ts** files a source map file is created but not for **.d.ts** files.

Comment: Will not have an impact if all your **.d.ts** contains are file references to **.ts** files. But if you put declarations inside **.d.ts** they will not become a part of the generated **.d.ts**. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16687938/390330

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but this feature might simply be lacking in the *alpha* version. Take into account that it's a *preview* of 0.9 and not all features are hence supported yet. There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213406/typescript-amd-implementation-bad-with-javascript-requirejs/16214223#16214223) known features lacking in 0.9 alpha as well. To be sure, you might want to go over to the TypeScript project site and ask them directly.

BTW that's a nice little trick to make sure each file references the definitions, although I agree with BASarat that with this setup you can't build it from command line.

At our project we only use those references for actual definition files, all other modules are imported as intented. We provide a few wrapper definition files like for example `general_libraries.d.ts` and `myproject.core.d.ts`. This way we can easily add or remove definition files of libraries without having to update this in each and every place they're references.

Also note that when you've got 2 modules, A & B, and A references a definition file C and B imports A, B knows about C without having to reference it again.